# Create a matrix from 3 tables

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a project table which lists every project.  I have a cost center table which lists every cost center.  I have an analyst table which shows the project, the cost center, and the analyst assigned to them. The projects and cost centers are dropdowns lists.  Every project should have every cost center included in it.  For every project and cost center combination, there should be an analyst assigned to it.  How do I see which ones I have missed?  The query I keep trying has two outer joins and Access doesn't like that.  With 30 projects and 15 cost centers it is easy to forget to assign an analyst to one of the combinations.

It would also be helpful to have some kind of query that easily shows who is assigned to what projects, preferably in a crosstab format (similar to a pivot table).  I think I can do that if I have the corect query that links these 3 tables together and shows every project with every cost center and which analyst is assigned to them.

If my setup with 3 tables is the main problem I can redo the database design.  I thought I was designing it correctly by having a seperate table for projects and cost centers and a 3rd table that combines them with the analysts.  But now that I can't figure out how to get this query to work I am thinking maybe that wasn't the best design idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  I figured it out.  I guess writing the question helped me think it through.

I used one query that had the project table and the cost center table in it.  This created a list of every possible combination.

I then made a second query that linked the first query to the analyst table.  I forced the query to show every combination from the first query and then tell me when an analyst matched that combination.  This way I get blanks for every time I missed adding an analyst.  It was also very easy to turn this 2nd query into a pivot table that shows all of the blanks.

Sorry again for posting this question.